# Regex Clarification

Tags: javascript, regex

I am relatively new to `regex`. I found this `regex` being used and was not able to understand how exactly it is working.

`([\(]*([\w][\/]?[\w]?(%)?(,)?)*|[\/.]|[\w]([\-\*|\+|\\|\<\>|\=]([\(]*[\w][\/]?(%)?[\)]?[\)]?(,)?)+)*[\)]?)*$/`

I understand most of the basic syntax but not able to understand what this means.

Any clarity on this will be appreciated! This is used in javascript so the tag.

Thanks!

Comment: This might help: https://www.debuggex.com/r/MyliJBLGcB1qhHQz , or this http://regex101.com/r/vO3aI9 . Whoever wrote that pattern didn't really know what they were doing, if I may say.

Comment: Lol this is before my time but this seems to meet the requirement. I need to make enhancements on this but I don't understand what this does. Thanks for the links, going through those might help me understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same without uneeded characters:

```
/(\(*(\w\/?\w?(%)?(,)?)*|[\/.]|\w([-*+\\<>=](\(*\w\/?(%)?\)?\)?(,)?)+)*\)?)*$/
```

This pattern can match this kind of string (or nothing):

```
(((a/b%,(((a/b%,///./././(((a/b%,k*((((((((P/%)),)
```

Comment: I would like to know why those characters where not needed. Thanks.

Comment: @Aashray: take a look at this link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: @Aashray The original expression had `[]` around single letters. This is redundant.

Comment: Thanks, this piece of code didn't meet the requirement. Pattern shown in your answer pretty much told me what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

your regex:

```
([\(]*([\w][\/]?[\w]?(%)?(,)?)*|[\/.]|[\w]([\-\*|\+|\\|\<\>|\=]([\(]*[\w][\/]?(%)?[\)]?[\)]?(,)?)+)*[\)]?)*$/
```

can be visualized as:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/nJ-irEWvQDUfUGma)

unless there is a typo in your regex, it will never match anything; the regex ends with `$/` which means **end of the string** followed by `/`, unless you are matching over multiple lines. If this was homework, I would say the teacher is making a bad joke because of the `$/` that doesn't usually match anything.

After some simplification you get:

```
(\(*(\w\/?\w?(%)?(,)?)*|[\/.]|\w([-*|+\\<>=](\(*\w\/?(%)?\)?\)?(,)?)+)*\)?)*$/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

If you don't care about grouping, then this is similar:

```
(\(|[\/.]|(\w\/?\w?%?,?)|\w([-*|+\\<>=](\(*\w\/?%?\)?\)?,?)+)*\)?)*$/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/tswc4uT6a8PtWkRW)

this takes advantage that `(a*|b*)*` can be simplified into `(a|b)*`

Comment: This was an existing piece of code. After checking through this, found out this was not tested properly.

Answer (score 0):

To learn more about regex REFER : [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/gA4bF6) give your code there and read explanation .

Your regex: `([\(]*([\w][\/]?[\w]?(%)?(,)?)*|[\/.]|[\w]([\-\*|\+|\\|\<\>|\=]([\(]*[\w][\/]?(%)?[\)]?[\)]?(,)?)+)*[\)]?)*$`

Will match anything like

```
(d/f%,
something
122
```

But will fail to match something like

```
--{}
```

**Explanation :**

[image]